# Shape of the region in region/geofence monitoring iOS

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, geofencing, clregion

CLRegion seems to be only circle supported, it's not very useful for a circle region, because in most cases, it is a polygon area.

So my question is:
In iOS7, is it possible to define polygon region for startRegionMonitoring.

Answer (score 3):

The Location and Maps Programming Guide states that  "In iOS 7.0 and later, you define geographical regions using the CLCircularRegion class." So, to use startRegionMonitoring your region needs to be a circle.

However, the Gimbal SDK (www.gimbal.com) allows you to create and monitor a polygonal region. In their Gimbal Manager portal, you can choose either Radial or Polygonal as a geofence type.  The polygonal choice comes with the following warning: "NOTE: A polygon smaller than 100m wide may have detection issues depending on WiFi availability, GPS and network strength."  You would then implement didGetPlaceEvent method to listen for place events. The Gimbal SDK would then call this method when it detects Entry/Exit for a place

Check out their quickstart guide for more info: http://gimbal.com/doc/ios_geofence_quickstart.html